# HTML/CSS adjust table width to column width not the oposite way

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

How do I make column width stop adjust to table width because following code will stretch columns past 50px when rendered:

```
<style>
   table {
      width:2000px;
   }

   td {
      width:50px;
   }
</style>

<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>      
</table>
```

then second question is opposite if I have no width set for table and have each column set to 200px how I make it build big table that's larger than screen. When I render below code table width adjusted to page width (100%) and each column has equal width within table not 200px

```
<style>
   td {
      width:200px;
   }
</style>

<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>      
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `display: inline-block;` will solve it

   ```
   td {
       width:50px;
       display: inline-block;
       /* if you want to write text in the cells longer than 50px, use also the followings */
       overflow: hidden;
       white-space: nowrap;
   }
   ```
2. `table-layout: fixed;` will solve it

   ```
   table {
       table-layout: fixed;
       width: 1px; /* required for table-layout */
   }

   td {     
       width:200px;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Removing the table width as you did in Q2 will solve this.

Question 2: You will need to check your containers because your table and columns will size to their container not the screen.

Ex:

```
body {
width:1000px;
}
```

OR

```
container{width:1200px;}
```

either of these or something similar will contain your table and not allow it's width to continue.